# How long should I cook sliced russert potatoes for mashing?

Tags: potatoes

I'm making [potatoes mousseline](http://www.finecooking.com/recipes/potatoes-mousseline.aspx) tomorrow morning for a 3pm service.

While the recipe doesn't call for it, I want to wash off as much starch as possible to minimize glueyness.  I'm planning on soaking overnight, and then rinsing after boiling. In order to maximize surface area for the soak and rinse (and for a faster prep) I plan on using a mandolin to cut the spuds into 1/2" slices.

However I suspect this will change the cooking time since the surface area has also changed.

Any suggestions or educated guesses?

Comment: cook until fork tender ?

Comment: Way too late to be useful -- but my solution is not to cook the potatoes in water.  Bake them 'til a potato with a line of holes from fork tines will pop open when you squeeze it from either end of the lines, then either peal & mash, or just use a ricer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are overthinking this somewhat on the starch front, I don't think that soaking and rinsing overnight, or the mandolin cut will reduce glueyness. It's the choice of potato and how you mash it that makes it gluey or not. If you use a ricer and non-waxy potatoes you should be fine. Just add lots of butter and they'll love it!

Slicing the potatoes thinly will make them cook faster due to the higher surface area, it also removes any room for error - the difference between undercooked and overcooked is all of a minute. Thin slicing can also be a problem for water circulation, leading to the potatoes on the bottom being mush and the top ones being raw, putting them in the pot vertically will prevent this. You are using 1/2 inch slices so you should be fine, but if you go thinner be aware of it. If you are doing thicker slices on a mandolin keep in mind the curvy end pieces will cook faster than the middle cuts. As for how much of a cooking time you'll save I think it may be a couple of minutes over cutting them into quarters, but it's hard to say exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Soaking them for around 30-40 minutes in a water bath of 160f/70c helps tremendously 
This site has another method that works very well but it results in a sweeter end product

http://modernistcuisine.com/2013/04/mastering-creamy-pureed-potatoes-no-fat-required/